# git: overwrite file's authorship

Tags: git

In our workflow we heavily rely on authorship of each file in our repo. E.g. we list all the files contributed by certain developer as follows:

```
git log --no-merges --author="SomeDev" --name-only --pretty=format:"" | sort -u
```

Usually we use merge to preserve this information but recently commits were rebased. How can we reassign authorship of each file to its original author?

Ideally it should

1. be done by one person on behalf of all the others (maybe somehow forging authorship using GIT_AUTHOR_NAME, GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL variables?);
2. avoid rewriting history, if possible, in order not to cause problems with future merges (if not possible - which workflow would minimize the merge troubles?)

Comment: Problem is, git doesn't track *files* but *content*. I don't question your end goal, but the tool itself is nor designed for that. Maybe consider using git data with another tool or with something you would build yourself?

Comment: @RomainValeri: to design a custom tool would be overkill. We do use git to track content, but if we use it in certain way (e.g. without rebase) we get additional benefits. So why introduce another tool? We prefer to use what we anyway have to use...

Comment: Question: are the commits distributed widely in time or are they usually localized? Maybe one way to hack this is to have the lead author do the rebase for the specific file.

Comment: you could start using the name of the last person who modified the file instead with `git blame` for example, it would also make it easy if a person leaves/joins the team

Comment: @astrochun: there are a lot of files, not only one. commits are distributed in time.

Comment: @Ivan: the nature of our project is so that a file once committed is rarely changed by others except for the original author, but it does happen. So relying on "last modified" would lead to false attribution.

Comment: @user1876484 I understand, I know this is not the answer to your question, but another idea coudl be to use the name of the owner of the first commit

Comment: "Commits were rebased".... so what?  rebasing changes committer info, not author info

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger: also `git filter-branch` was used... anyway author info was changed somehow...

Comment: @Ivan: could you, please, show the command that "uses the name of the owner of the first commit"?

Comment: @user1876484 `git log --pretty=format:%an | tail -1` you can use this